# How to prove that f(w)=0

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let I=[a,b] , let f:$\rightarrow$R is continuous on I,and assume f(a) < 0 and f(b)>0 .let W={x$\in$I:f(x)<0},and let w:=supW .prove that f(w)=0.

My work: since w=supW then either w$\in$W or w is a limit point of W. If w is in W then this question does not make any sense so w is a limit point of W and f(w)$\geq$0. Since w is a limit point there exist a sequence ($x_n$) in W such that it converges to w. But after that I cannot proceed.

Comment: IVT, then using the fact it’s cont. at the points where f =0.

Comment: Sir i dont get it please explain

Comment: Please use Mathjac to render the math.

Comment: "tIf w is in W then this question does not make any sense"  Why the heck not? Of course $w = \sup \{x|x\in I; f(x) < 0\}$ and $f(w) < 0$ makes sense.  It's *wrong*.  But it makes perfect sense.

Comment: "either w∈W or w is a limit point of W"  Those are not mutually exclussive.  It could be both. "If w is in W then this question does not make any sense" ???????  "so w is a limit point of W and f(w)≥0"  It could be that $w$ is a limit point and $f(w) < 0$.  That would mean that $w$ is a limit point that is in the set which is completely possible.

Comment: Yes i am wrong i was confuse because if we consider the set (0,1)$\cup${2} then 2 is a supremum of this set but 2 is not a limit point of the set. I was thinking if w was in W then f(w) is not equal to 0 so it does not make sense. Sorry if i do something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$w=\sup W\implies w=\lim_{n\to+\infty}w_n\;\;$$

with $ w_n\in W$.

$$f(w_n)<0\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}f(w_n)\le 0$$

$$\implies f(\lim_{n\to+\infty}w_n)\le 0$$
$$\implies \color{red}{f(w)\le 0}$$

On the other hand, for $ n$ great enough, $ f(w+\frac 1n)\ge 0$
because $w+\frac 1n \notin W$
thus

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(w+\frac 1n)\ge 0$$
$$\implies f(\lim_{n\to+\infty}(w+\frac 1n))\ge 0$$
$$\implies \color{red}{f(w)\ge 0}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{c_n\}\subset W$ a sequence s.t. $c_n\to w=\sup W$. Obviously, $f(w)\leq 0$ since $f(c_n)\leq 0$ for all $n$. Moreover, $$f\left(w+\frac{1}{n}\right)\geq 0$$
for all $n$ (take $n$ big enough to have $w+\frac{1}{n}\in I$). Therefore $f(w)\geq 0$.